# How to group one dimension based on another dimension grouping in crossfilter?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

In my problem, I have data about customers and seller:

```
customer, seller, amount
cus1, sel1, 78
cus2, sel1, 34
cus3, sel2, 25
cus2, sel1, 13
cus2, sel1, 11
cus3, sel2, 18
cus4, sel3, 50
```

...I would like to know how many customers each seller have. Thus I would like to construct a row chart showing the top 10 sellers with the biggest amount of clients.

I tried:

```
this.sellerDim = this.ndx.dimension(function(d: any) {return d.seller;});
this.customerDim = this.ndx.dimension(function(d: any) {return d.customer;});

this.sellerCount = this.sellerDim.group();
```

I also tried something like:

```
this.sellerCount = this.sellerDim.group().reduceSum(function(d:any){return d.customerDim});
```

...but it did not work out.

for displaying the chart I am using:

```
this.topSellerChart = dc.rowChart("#chart-row");

this.topSellerChart.data(function(d: any){
                                return d.order(function (d: any) {
                                    return d;
                                }).top(10);
                             })
                      .dimension(this.sellerDim)
                      .group(this.sellerCount)
                      .elasticX(true)
                      .controlsUseVisibility(true);
```

anyhow I and convinced that the mistake is during the `.group()` creation.

So, does anyone know how can I **group sellers without counting more then once the same customer**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [crossfilter "double grouping" where key is the value of another reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42109965/crossfilter-double-grouping-where-key-is-the-value-of-another-reduction)

Comment: This is often called a "double grouping" - it's not something crossfilter directly supports but it can be done. I've linked one previous question but lmk if it doesn't apply and I'll take another look.

Comment: Isn't it more like what I usually call exception aggregation? You want the number of unique customers for each seller, right? I think this answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391290/avoid-multiple-sums-in-custom-crossfilter-reduce-functions/42400837#42400837